# Physical keyboard shortcuts that use the "search" key?

Tags: keyboard

According to the physical keyboard configuration on my android phone, there are a number of keyboard shortcuts that involve the "search" key. E.g. "+⏎" for home. I've included a screenshot below showing the complete list. I am running LineageOS 16.0 (Android 9); the screenshot comes from the "Physical keyboard" configuration (System -> Languages & input -> Physical keyboard).

What key is Android expecting for the "" key?

I have a keyboard configured with a "Search" key. Using `evtest` on my Linux box, I can see the keyboard is sending the `KEY_SEARCH` keycode:

```
Event: time 1601635686.628475, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 217 (KEY_SEARCH), value 1
```

This comes from the "USB-HID Keyboard Consumer Control" device.

When connected to my phone, none of the shortcuts involving the search key appear to work. I am wondering if I just need to remap the search key to send something different?

[image]

Comment: I never heared of a "search key" on a physical keyboard. The Android display keaboard can have a search key in certain situations. I would assume that the commands on the posted screen shots refer to the software keyboard. See e.g. bottom right in this screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjsAr.png

Comment: The posted screenshot comes directly from the "Physical keyboard" configuration (`System -> Languages & input -> Physical keyboard`), so pretty sure it's not referring to the software keyboard. This is LineageOS 16.0 (Android 9).

Comment: The Search key here actually refers to the OS key(Windows/Command/Super key). On some ROMs (e.g. Samsung's One UI), this search button is replaced by "OS" (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfPrt.png))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Search key here in Android refers to the OS key(Windows/Command/Super keys), so you would use the OS key + other combinations to activate the shortcut.

On some ROMs, such as One UI, this search key is replaced by "OS".

[image]

I guess why this is called the Search key is because when you press on it(OS key), it will activate the Search app(e.g. Google) and on newer systems, this is configured to activate the default assistant app(e.g. Google Assistant)

Answer (score 1):

I've just connected my physical keyboard to my phone for the first time and was also shown that list of shortcuts. I too wonder what the Search key is on my keyboard. As I read you message I thought.... Maybe it's the key normally labeled as "Win" or "OS" etc. It's often considered a special key. Tried it.. Eg Win+C and yup, in opened up my Contacts app! :-)